# Value of SelectList not getting captured

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

I have a `Selectlist` in my Visualforce page and I'm passing the values from the controller. The value selected is not getting captured. The code is given below.

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="createB2BorB2CController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
   <apex:pageMessages />
   <apex:form >
   <apex:sectionHeader title="Case"/>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Account Creation">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Save}"/>
           <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
       <apex:pageblockSection title="Account Type" id="companyType">
           <apex:selectList label="Account Type" value="{!accountType}" multiselect = "false" size="1">
              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="cmpny"/>
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!type}"/>
           </apex:selectList>
           <apex:outputPanel id="cmpny" >
           <apex:InputText label = "Company" value="{!company}" rendered="{!IF(accountType  == 'B2B' ,true,false)}" required = "true"/>
           </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:pageblockSection>
      <apex:pageblockSection title="Personal Information">
           <apex:InputText label = "First Name" value="{!firstName}" />
           <apex:InputText label = "Last Name" value="{!lastName}" required = "true"/> 
      </apex:pageblockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller

```
public without sharing class createB2BorB2CController{
    public String accountType {get;set;}
    public String company {get;set;}
    public String firstName {get;set;}
    public String lastName {get;set;}
    public Id caseId;
    Account newAcc = null;
    public PageReference redirectPage;

    public createB2BorB2CController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        redirectPage = new PageReference('/'+caseId);
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getType(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new Selectoption('None','None'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('B2C','B2C'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('B2B','B2B'));
        return options;
    }

    public pageReference save(){
        if(accountType == 'B2B' && company == NULL){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'If the Account type is B2B, Company should be filled'));
            return null;
        }
        if(lastName == NULL){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Last Name cannot be empty'));
            return null;
        }
        if(company != NULL){
            Account acc = null;
            try{
                newAcc = [Select Id, Name from Account WHERE Name =: Company LIMIT 1];
            }catch(exception e){
                Acc = new Account(Name = Company);
                try{
                    insert acc;
                }catch(exception e1){}
            }
            Contact con = new Contact (FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName, AccountId = newAcc != NULL? newAcc.Id : acc.Id);
            try{
                insert con;
            }catch(Exception e){}
            Case c = new Case (id = caseId, ContactId = con.Id);
            try{
                update c;
            }catch(exception e){}
        }
        else{
            Account acc = new Account(FirstName = firstName, lastName = lastName);
            try{
                insert acc;
            }catch(exception e){}
            Case c = new Case (id = caseId, AccountId = acc.Id);
            try{
                update c;
            }catch(exception e){}
        }
        return redirectPage;
    }

    public pageReference cancel(){
        return redirectPage;
    }
}
```

The gist is when the Account Type is selected as 'B2B', the field `Company` has to rendered. But the value of `Account Type` is returning NULL

Answer (score 0):

I figured the error after a lot of trial and error.

I had to remove `required = "true"` from

```
<apex:InputText label = "Company" value="{!company}" rendered="{!IF(accountType  == 'B2B' ,true,false)}" required = "true"/>
```

and it worked.